# How to get icons from the icons folder of eclipse plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have some Icons in the Icons Folder of my plugin Project, which i want to use them in setting images in columns of my TreeViewer.

I have tried in two ways to get the Image

1)

```
       Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(INF2TreeLabelProvider.class);
    URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(icons/abc.png), null);
    ImageDescriptor imageDcr = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
    Image image = imageDcr.createImage();
```

2)

```
 ImageDescriptor imgDesc = AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin("plugin-name", icons/abc.png);
 Image image = imgDesc.createImage();
```

With code snippet 1) , i get a null URL object and with code snippet 2) , i get a null ImageDescriptor

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Is the `icons` folder in the `src` directory?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, its in the same Level as that of 'src'.

Comment: Have you tried using the `"/icons/abc.png"` path instead?

Comment: i just tried that, even that is not working

Comment: You will need to ensure that Eclipse is including the `icon`s directory within it's classpath...Don't use Eclipse, but you should be able to find suggestions SO...seen a few

Comment: I use the FileLocator method all the time. Check that you are getting the correct Bundle from FrameworkUtil.

Comment: What if `FrameworkUtil.getBundle()` returns `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including icons/ directory in build.properties file? Something like:

```
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
           META-INF/,\
           .,\
           icons/,\
           OSGI-INF/
```